# Why the custom deleter doesn't increase the size of unique_ptr object?

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

I have written this test code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int *testRaw = nullptr;
    cout << sizeof(testRaw) << endl;

    unique_ptr<int> testUnique(nullptr);
    cout << sizeof(testUnique) << endl;

    auto CustomeDeleter = [](int *ptr)
    {
        cout << *ptr;
        delete ptr;
    };

    unique_ptr<int, decltype(CustomeDeleter)> testUniqueCustom(nullptr, CustomeDeleter);
    cout << sizeof(testUniqueCustom) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With the compiler clang-700.1.81 my output is:

```
8
8
8
```

How could it be that the custom deleter didn't increase the pointer size? 
As I understand lambda function is an object of the closure type, and the size of any class always > 0 in C++.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe because executable code is not considered in the size calculation of an object.

Comment: Hint - capture a variable in your lambda and see the results. And then look at the `sizeof` of an empty struct (even with a non-virtual member function).

Comment: empty base class optimization.